# Consuming again messages from kafka log compaction topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring application with a Kafka consumer using a     @KafkaListerner annotation. The topic being consumed is log compacted and we might have the scenario where we must consume again the topic messages. What's the best way to achieve this programmatically? We don't control the Kafka topic configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```java
    @KafkaListener(...)
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if (this.resetNeeded) {
            consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
            this.resetNeeded = false;
        }
    }
```

If you want to reset when the listener is idle (no records) you can enable idle events and perform the seeks by listening for a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` in an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` method.

The event has a reference to the consumer.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So58769796Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58769796Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so58769796", topics = "so58769796")
    public void listen1(String value, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        System.out.println("One:" + key + ":" + value);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so58769796a", topics = "so58769796")
    public void listen2(String value, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        System.out.println("Two:" + key + ":" + value);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so58769796")
                .compact()
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(1)
                .build();
    }

    boolean reset;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so58769796", "foo", "bar");
            System.out.println("Hit enter to rewind");
            System.in.read();
            this.reset = true;
        };
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listen(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (this.reset && event.getListenerId().startsWith("so58769796-")) {
            event.getConsumer().seekToBeginning(event.getConsumer().assignment());
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5000
```

**EDIT2**

Here's another technique - in this case we rewind each time the app starts (and on demand)...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So58769796Application implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58769796Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so58769796", topics = "so58769796")
    public void listen(String value, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so58769796")
                .compact()
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {

        return args -> {
            template.send("so58769796", "foo", "bar");
            System.out.println("Hit enter to rewind");
            System.in.read();
            registry.getListenerContainer("so58769796").stop();
            registry.getListenerContainer("so58769796").start();
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        assignments.keySet().forEach(tp -> callback.seekToBeginning(tp.topic(), tp.partition()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The idea is more reset on demand (when we explicitly want). Is it possible ?

Comment: See the edit to my answer for an example. The second edit shows another technique, by implementing `ConsumerSeekAware`,

Comment: That's precisely what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: It's working but what's happening is that is resetting all my consumers from different topics in the application, instead of only the one where I'm using this flag. Could this behaviour be because of the groupid?

Comment: If you have multiple `@KafkaListener`s in the same `ConsumerSeekAware` class it will apply to them all; you should put the one you want to rewind in its own class.

Comment: I'm using the first approach with an @EventListener in each consumer,  but still every topics are being resetted.

Comment: You have to check the `listenerId` property in the event (if your `id` is `foo` use `event.getListenerId().startsWith("foo-")` - I updated my first EDIT.