# @KafkaListner - Skip older messages aka Receive only new messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the factory bean:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        CustomConsumerRebalanceListener consumerRebalanceListener, ConsumerFactory consumerFactory, CustomConfiguration customConfiguration) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    factory.setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    factory.setConcurrency(customConfiguration.getConcurrency());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(consumerRebalanceListener);
    return factory;
}
```

here is my listner:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic}")
    private synchronized void consumeKafkaQueue(@Payload String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        ...
    }
```

How can i configure the listener to receive only new messages and not get old messages on startup?

Comment: I've never used the lib, but i'd guess `acknowledgment.acknowledge();`

Comment: The `Acknowledgment` instance only applies to the current message; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have your listener implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and seek to the end when the partitions are assigned. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769796/consuming-again-messages-from-kafka-log-compaction-topic/58770070#58770070) and specifically, the example after **EDIT2**; use `seekToEnd` instead.

Or, you can use `auto.offset.reset=latest` and use a unique `group.id` each time the app starts.

Also

```
factory.setConcurrency(customConfiguration.getConcurrency());
```

Using a `synchronized` listener method will defeat the concurrency; additional threads will wait on the synchronization.