# Iterating through kafka topic multiple times using spring

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I would like to iterate through Kafka DL topic multiple times. I could find an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/itzg/e3ebfd7aec220bf0522e23a65b1296c8). Another one could be using spring cloud. Not sure whether I can iterate over again and again with these.

Which one could be better? Or is there any better approach other than the above two?

A consumer with seek option to the oldest available offset? If this is the better approach, how can we seek to the earliest? I know that the consumer-auto-offset-reset property has got relevance only when a new consumer group is created which is not practical in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **EDIT2** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769796/consuming-again-messages-from-kafka-log-compaction-topic/58770070#58770070) for how to seek to the beginning each time the application starts.

Comment: Ok Garry Russel. If we have randomly distributed multiple partitions, how this will work?

Comment: What do you mean? This code `assignments.keySet().forEach(tp -> callback.seekToBeginning(tp.topic(), tp.partition()));` Seeks all the partitions. Since 2.3.4, you can use `callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet())` instead of iterating.