# How to seek a particular offset in kafka listener method?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset, spring-kafka

I am trying to seek offset from a SQL database in my kafka listener method .
I have used registerSeekCallback method in my code but this method gets invoked when we run the consumer (or container is started) . Let's say my consumer is running and last committed offset is 20 in MySql database. I manually change the last committed offset in Mysql database to 11 but my consumer will keep reading  from 21 unless i restart my consumer(container restarted) . I am looking out for any option if i can override or seek offset in my listener method itself. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Listen implements ConsumerSeekAware 
{
 @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback)

    {
//      fetching offset from a database 
        Integer offset = offsetService.getOffset();
        callback.seek("topic-name",0,offset);

    }
 @KafkaListener(topics = "topic-name", groupId = "group")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord record Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception 
  {
//    processing the record 

      acknowledgment.acknowledge();    //manually commiting the record
//    committing the offset to MySQL database
  }
}
```

Editing with new listener method :-

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-name", groupId = "group")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord record Acknowledgment acknowledgment, 
  @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer)) throws Exception {
       // seeking old offset stored in database (which is 11 )
        consumer.seek(partition,offsetService.getOffset());
        log.info("record offset is {} and value is {}" , record.offset(),record.value() );
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

In database my last committed offset is 11 and last committed offset on kafka end is 21. When i wrote a new record in kafka topic(i.e on offset 22) , my consumer triggers and processes 22 offset first then it goes back to seek offset 11 & start processing from there.
why is it consuming offset 22 first although i am seeking offset 11 ?

With my above code , every time i write a new message to my kafka top it processes that record first then it seeks the offset present in my database . Is there any way i can avoid that ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several techniques in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769796/consuming-again-messages-from-kafka-log-compaction-topic/58770070#58770070).

Bear in mind that performing a seek on the consumer will not take effect until the next poll (any records fetched on the last poll will be sent to the consumer first).

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63429201Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63429201Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, Listener listener) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so63429201", i % 3,  null, "foo" + i));
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            listener.seekToTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 11000);
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            listener.seekToOffset(new TopicPartition("so63429201", 0), 11);
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63429201").partitions(3).replicas(1).build();
    }

}

@Component
class Listener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63429201", topics = "so63429201", concurrency = "2")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        System.out.println(assignments);
        super.onPartitionsAssigned(assignments, callback);
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }

    public void seekToTime(long time) {
        getSeekCallbacks().forEach((tp, callback) -> callback.seekToTimestamp(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), time));
    }

    public void seekToOffset(TopicPartition tp, long offset) {
        getSeekCallbackFor(tp).seek(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), offset);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary . I have tried as you have suggested but somehow it is not working . I have edited my original question & added more details . Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are acknowledging the current record after the seek so, of course, that offset is now committed; making the seek redundant.

Comment: I have removed the acknowledgement and change the auto commit property to true .But it is still processing the current offset first then it it is seeking my old offset(11) stored in a database & processing all the offsets thereafter. My concern why is it processing current offset (22) when i am seeing the old offset(11) . It would be really helpful if you can provide small piece of listener method code wherein we are overriding the committed offset(stored on kafka cluster)  by an offset(stored outside of kafka cluster ) every time a new message publish to kafka topic.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; if the current record being processed is 22, then that is what it is; the seek will only take effect on the next poll; as I said, if there are other records already fetched by the previous poll, you will see those first; you can set `max.poll.records=1` to prevent that.

Comment: Let me rephrase what i am trying to achieve here:-.Last committed offset on kafka(__consumer_offset__) topic is 21 .Producer will write the next message from offset 22 onwards. I am doing my own offset management outside KAFKA cluster(MYSQL) . I go & update offset in my MYSQL table to 11 because i want to seek  messages(starting from offset 11 ). After that, producer publishes a message to offset 22. As soon as it publishes , my kafka listener methods will get triggered .Instead of consuming offset 22 first. I want to start consuming from offset 11(stored in MYSQL)

Comment: Well, you can't do the seek within the listener method then, it will only be triggered when #22 arrives. If you are storing the offsets outside of Kafka, you shouldn't be acknowledging at all. Extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` and perform the initial seeks in `onPartitionsAssigned`. For resetting the offsets at runtime, use `getSeekCallbackFor(topicPartition)` or `getSeekCallbacks()`. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference) - scroll down to the last example.

Comment: Thanks gary for your help ! I will try this out.

Comment: @Nitish I am also working on the same requirements, Are you able to get this working?

Answer (score -1):

Starting with spring kafka `version 2.5.5`, we can apply an initial offset to all assigned partitions:

```
        @KafkaListener( groupId = "group_json", containerFactory = "userKafkaListenerFactory", topicPartitions =
                {@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition(topic = "Kafka_Topic", partitions = {"0"},
                        partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "3")),
                        @org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition(topic = "Kafka_Topic_2", partitions = {"0"},
                                partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "4"))
                })
        public void consumeJson(User user, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {

            /*
            Reading the message into a String variable.
             */
            String message = consumerRecord.value().toString();
}
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference